# C++11 g++ with brace-enclosed initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I'm new to programming so I apologize if this is an obvious question, however I am having trouble with the syntax presented to me in a book (Programming Principles and Practice using C++ 2nd Edition by the creator of C++, Bjarne Stroustrup).  In it, the following is presented for creating a vector of strings:

```
vector<string> philosopher
    ={"Kant","Plato","Hume","Kierkegaard"};
```

However, when passing this through g++ it doesn't like it.  My code is as follows:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"  //The author's library for his examples

int main()
{
  vector<string>philosopher
    ={"Kant","Plato","Hume","Kierkegaard"};

}
```

I'm getting an error compiling:

```
g++ vecttest.cpp -std=c++11
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.0/ext/hash_map:60:0,
             from /usr/include/std_lib_facilities.h:34,
             from vecttest.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.0/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning: #warning 
This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may 
be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a 
non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing     
of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. 
To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated. [-Wcpp]
#warning \
^
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.0/locale:41:0,
             from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.0/iomanip:43,
             from /usr/include/std_lib_facilities.h:212,
             from vecttest.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/locale_facets_nonio.h:1869:5: error: 
template-id  ‘do_get<>’ for 
‘String std::messages<char>::do_get(std::messages_base::catalog, int, int, 
const String&) const’ does not match any template declaration
 messages<char>::do_get(catalog, int, int, const string&) const;
 ^
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/locale_facets_nonio.h:1869:62: note: 
saw 1 ‘template<>’, need 2 for specializing a member function template
 messages<char>::do_get(catalog, int, int, const string&) const;
                                                          ^
vecttest.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
vecttest.cpp:8:42: error: could not convert ‘{"Kant", "Plato", 
"Hume","Kierkegaard"}’from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Vector<String>’
 ={"Kant","Plato","Hume","Kierkegaard"};
```

I thought maybe my version of GCC was older (Which it was at 4.7) so I updated it to 4.9:

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9.0/configure
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.0 (GCC)
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you get warning regarding obsolete headers, try including `<vector>` and `<string>` instead

Comment: Are you sure you have pasted the right code? Your code says `vector<string>` while the error message says `vector<String>`.

Comment: Just remove the mystery header and include the ones that are required. And use `std::` where appropriate.

Comment: Disgusting macro hacks strike again...

Comment: There's a newer version of that header for C++11 found [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h) that seems to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going wrong with the use of this `std_lib_facilities.h`. [Looking at it online](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h), it shows:

```
template< class T> struct Vector : public std::vector<T> {
    ...
};

// disgusting macro hack to get a range checked vector:
#define vector Vector
```

Unfortunately, this custom `Vector` template class lacks some constructors that `std::vector` does have.

Use `std::vector` directly and it'll work. It's supported in GCC 4.4 and newer.

Note: to use `std::vector`, you need to make sure you *don't* use `std_lib_facilities.h` at all, or use `#undef vector`. Macro definitions are problematic and pay no attention to namespaces, so `std::vector` would become the non-existent `std::Vector`.

Note 2: T.C. rightly comments that similar issues also exist for `string`: use `std::string` instead.

Comment: There's also a `#define string String` in that header that caused the `<iomanip>` compile error. Fun times...

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, added a note of that.

Comment: @user3789175 He provides a new version for C++11 [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h) that seems to [compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a41dbf2e6b83a142) with your code. The one linked in this answer (and you used) is for the first edition, which uses C++98.

Comment: You're right, that was the issue.  I still don't like using a non-standard library, even to learn, but I'm trusting the book on it for now.  I updated the library file and things are all fine now.  Thank you for your help.